# Event listener not working in laravel and not giving any error

Tags: laravel

I am just trying to set up an email notification in laravel and tried to do a simple event first to test how it works but for some reason it's not working

I registered the event and listener in the eventserviceprovider and used artisan command to generate event and listener files

**EventServiceProvider**

```php
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    'App\Events\RepEmail' => [
        'App\Listeners\RepEmail',
    ],
];
```

**RepEmail.php** (event)

```
     public $message;

     public function __construct($message)
     {
     $this->message = $message;
     }
```

Listener - RepEmail.php

```
public function handle(RepEmail $event)
{
    dd($event);     
}
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('event', function () {
    event(new RepEmail('just message test'));
});
```

This is just giving me a blank screen if I go to mysite/event - no errors

Comment: First, check your logs - a blank page in PHP where you expect output is frequently a sign there's details of a 500 error lurking in them. Second, `event` doesn't output anything, so try `Log::debug('HELLO')` in your handler and see if that appears in the logs.

Comment: Hi I tried Log:debug but still nothing showing in the logs either

Comment: Is the `RepEmail` class in the `event(new RepEmail('just message test'))` the `App\Events\RepEmail` or `App\Listeners\RepEmail`? It should be `App\Events\RepEmail`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , actually it was a namespace issue in the evenserviceprovider, I had to put Mysite\App\App\Events and same for listener. It works now

Answer (score 0):

Very Old question, new answer.

Clear your event cache.

> php artisan event:cache

or

> php artisan event:clear